# Dockerfile COPY does not work with wildcards

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile, wildcard

According to [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) the COPY instruction of Dockerfile should work with wildcards. But when I try to build the Dockerfile below on a Windows machine, it throws an "invalid operation" without giving further details.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1809 AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./

RUN dotnet build -c Debug -o out
RUN dotnet pack ./MyApp -c Debug

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-nanoserver-1809
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app/out .
COPY --from=build /app/MyApp/bin/Debug/*.nupkg .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

The app in question is a simple Hello World which I wanted to use to test something entirely unrealted, but this really bothers me. I know this has been brought up in a lot of questions on this site, but non of them seem to give an actual answer why this function, that is statet in the documentation, does not work. Instead the answers either say "The documentation says that it works", "[insert weird workaround]" or "It was caused by some other bug". I also didn't see that specific error beeing mentioned.

**Update**

I've narrowed down the problem to copying files between two images in a multi-stage build. Consider the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1809 AS build

COPY *.txt ./

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-nanoserver-1809

COPY --from=build *.txt ./
```

If you execute *docker build*, the first step works, provided you have a .txt file parallel to your Dockerfile. The second step however, fails with an invalid function error. If you replace the asterix with the name of the .txt file, it works.

Comment: are you sure it's not simply the missing / in the end of the COPY instruction?

Comment: Start by building only your build stage, run the container, and show the directory listing of `/app/MyApp/bin/Debug`

Comment: @Stefano It's not

Comment: @BMitch The directory is correct. When I specify a file inside it the build completes.

Comment: @TigersEye120 please provide a [mcve], including the commands you are running and their output.

Comment: @BMitch Done that

Comment: Guess its very late to answer this, but this would work on windows:
`COPY .\build\*.txt ./`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce your mcve (using busybox since it's smaller and I'm not on Windows). Here's the output of my commands showing that the COPY command works as expected:

```
$ touch example.txt

$ vi Dockerfile

$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM busybox as build
COPY *.txt ./

FROM busybox as release
COPY --from=build *.txt ./

$ docker build -t test-63706476 .
[+] Building 0.3s (7/8)
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 132B                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/busybox:latest                        0.0s
 => CACHED [build 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/busybox                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 32B                                                         0.0s
 => [build 2/2] COPY *.txt ./                                                            0.1s
 => exporting to image                                                                   0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                  0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:ea328f739e7e795efb5c54ca4018b0ab56b52ae09016775f58097a5f8e6  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/test-63706476                                         0.0s

$ docker run -it --rm test-63706476 sh
/ # ls
bin          etc          home         root         tmp          var
dev          example.txt  proc         sys          usr
/ # exit
```

Comment: When switching to Linux containers it works for me too, while it still isn't working when using a different Windows Base Image. So I would assume it's a problem specific to Windows Docker-Hosts. I guess I should make a ticket somewhere...

Comment: @TigersEye120 If you have an error message, try searching for it here: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards in COPY command will not work for Windows.

You can find more details on

https://forums.docker.com/t/dockerfile-copy-does-not-work-with-wildcard/95212